# Custom cart items price calculation for Woocommerce Bookings

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, woocommerce-bookings

I want to know how to update the price calculation depending on some internal coding. This is the price that needs to go into the cart item and thus far, the cart item shows only the base cost of the product.

Technically the price should be altered, when a product is added to the cart.

I figured it had to be calculated like this:

```
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
    if ($value['product_id'] == $product_id) {
        $value['data']->set_price($price);
    }  
}
```

Since this does not do the trick, where/when do I need to put the set_price() function. When this is called, the cart is still empty and the loop is not entered.

My problem seems to be with Woocommerce Bookings as with following line $this->price is not set and then get_base_cost is called resulting in only showing the base cost and not the "recalculated" price. Since it is a bookable product, this seems to make it more tricky.

```
public function get_price($context = ‘view’) {
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $this->price ? $this->price : $this->get_base_cost(), $this );
}
```

Looking closely at $this I can at least see both prices within the class_wc_product_booking, where 300 is the "base cost" and 250 the recalculated price that has to be paid.

I did delete a lot of the array that should not be relevant for this issue.

```
WC_Product_Booking Object ( 
[availability_rules:WC_Product_Booking:private] =>  Array ( ) 
[object_type:protected] => product 
[post_type:protected] => product 
[cache_group:protected] => products 
[data:protected] => 
    Array ( 
        [name] => Booking Test 
        [slug] => Booking Test
        [sku] => 
        [price] => 300
        [regular_price] => 
        [sale_price] => 
        [rating_counts] => Array ( ) 
        [average_rating] => 0 
        [review_count] => 0
    ) 
[supports:protected] => Array ( ) 
[id:protected] => 1708 
[changes:protected] => Array ( [price] => 250 ) 
[meta_data:protected] => 
[product_type] => booking
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to change the price custom way before sending to the cart if yes then you need to send by session the below two hooks will help a lot

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item' , 'set_woo_prices');
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session',  'set_session_prices', 20 , 3 );

function set_woo_prices( $woo_data ) {
  session_start();    
  $tac_dd_discounted_price = $_SESSION['']; // get the updated new price field 

  if ( ! isset($tac_dd_discounted_price ) || empty ($tac_dd_discounted_price ) ) { return $woo_data; }
  $woo_data['data']->set_price( $tac_dd_discounted_price );
  $woo_data['my_price'] = $tac_dd_discounted_price;
  return $woo_data;
}

function  set_session_prices ( $woo_data , $values , $key ) {
    if ( ! isset( $woo_data['my_price'] ) || empty ( $woo_data['my_price'] ) ) { return $woo_data; }
    $woo_data['data']->set_price( $woo_data['my_price'] );
    return $woo_data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This needs to be done on `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` action hook, to work. Below a working example where it adds 30 to each product price in cart items:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_cart_item_price', 10, 1 );
function custom_cart_item_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price(); // Get the product price
        $new_price = $price + 30; // the calculation
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( $new_price ); // Set the new price
    }
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

---

> **Note:** `global $woocommerce;` with `$woocommerce->cart` is outdated and has been replaced by **`WC()->cart`** instead.

Comment: I copied your code into the functions.php and the cart price did not change at all?

Also, I am doing some price calculations depending on a form and would need that price to be within the custom_cart_item_price function?

Comment: @achiever This code works add it's very classic (there is a lot of answers with it on SO)… May be it could be better that you update your question with the related code of your calculations… we don't know where and how you are making this actually. So this way we could better help you. You should also give us some information related to the WooCommerce version you are using. The new answer from **Aakanksh Patel** is working fine too.

Comment: I am sure the code works! It does not change "my" price yet, but that could have many reasons. Woocommerce v. 3.2.5

Comment: I have to use $cart_item['data']->price = $wp_session["new_price"]; - but this will change the price in the cart correctly.
But this will change the price of all items with the same product id and not for the "single" added product.

Comment: @achiever  You need to adapt the code for your case… Your session variable should contain also the product ID and the price in a kind of array. This way you can apply it on the corresponding product ID. Is not so simple as you can see...