# How can i get cart items using user_id or session id in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api, woocommerce

I am using Rest API for building mobile application. I am using cart api but there is no any method to get cart items using user id.

So, It would be appreciated if anyone have solved this type of issue. Please let me know how to get the cart items using user id or session id in woocommerce (Wordpress).

Thanks you

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow please add your code here because there no one can identify your problem until and unless but you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882716/woocommerce-custom-cart-items-price-calculation/47883886#47883886 to get you nearby issue

Comment: I am using $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart(). It is working fine on web but not on Android